# Kafka Consumer Shutdown in Tomcat

Tags: spring-kafka

We are deploying kafka consumers  in tomcat servers .Consumers are built using spring-kafka 2.1.7. Each tc container  can have multiple consumers (using ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory)  belonging to   the same  consumer group.As a general pattern consumers
read from a  topic and produce to another topic in  a transactional way in my use case.Tc servers are started and stopped by usual startup and shutdown shell scripts. For a graceful shutdown of consumer should the container be stopped by calling container.stop from within
a shutdown hook ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concern isn't clear. The `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` is a Spring bean, therefore its lifecylce is controlled by the Spring `ApplicationContext`. If this one is deployed properly into Tomcat, an appropriate shutdown hook is registered there by [default](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-shutdown):

> Spring’s web-based `ApplicationContext` implementations already have code in place to shut down the Spring IoC container gracefully when the relevant web application is shut down.

Comment: Thanks Artem. Let me re phrase a bit . If I have @KafkaListener  and tomcat is shutdown is there a chance for  message loss or duplicates.I am letting the container manage the transaction with  AckMode.RECORD . Thinking of a scenario where  a message is read from the  source topic and written to destination topic but tc container is shutdown before commit happens on the offsets topic.An unrelated question -  can I do retries in a transactional producer if I use Ackmode.BATCH or COUNT .Like if  a batch fails can the retry happen from the record that was failed or can this cause duplicate record

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't look like related question to what we have had originally. If you use `KafkaTransactionManager` from the consumer to the producer, you are not going to lose anything. This is exactly what is Kafka exactly once: https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/. The commits for the offsets are send to the producer to be applied on TX commit.